# If-else inside a for loop not working - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop, if-statement

I have an array "contacts" with a few properties. My function uses a for to check if the firstName property of each contact matches the name parameter of my function, if it does, it checks if such contact has a property that matches the prop parameter (an if inside the previous if). Both "ifs" have corresponding "elses": "no such property", "not such contact".

Code is very simple actually:

```
var contacts = [
  {
    "firstName": "Akira",
    "lastName": "Laine",
    "number": "0543236543",
    "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Harry",
    "lastName": "Potter",
    "number": "0994372684",
    "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Kristian",
    "lastName": "Vos",
    "number": "unknown",
    "likes": ["JavaScript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
  }
];


function lookUpProfile(name, prop) {

  for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {

    if (contacts[i].firstName === name) {

      if (contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        return contacts[i][prop];
      }
      else {
        return "No such property";
      }
    }
    else {
      return "No such contact";}
  }  
}

console.log(lookUpProfile("Harry", "likes"));
```

Following lines work perfectly:

```
console.log(lookUpProfile("Akira", "likes"));
console.log(lookUpProfile("Akira", "lala"));
```

Now, If I put any other firsNames of the rest of the elements:

```
console.log(lookUpProfile("Harry", "likes"));
console.log(lookUpProfile("Kristian", "likes"));
```

it returns "No such contact".... :/

Comment: you are using `return` within `for` loop, which will interrupt your for loop when no match is found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're returning `No such contact` in the first loop iteration. Place this at the bottom of your function after the loop as a catch-all.

```js
var contacts=[{"firstName":"Akira","lastName":"Laine","number":"0543236543","likes":["Pizza","Coding","Brownie Points"]},{"firstName":"Harry","lastName":"Potter","number":"0994372684","likes":["Hogwarts","Magic","Hagrid"]},{"firstName":"Kristian","lastName":"Vos","number":"unknown","likes":["JavaScript","Gaming","Foxes"]}]

function lookUpProfile(name, prop) {

  for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {

    if (contacts[i].firstName === name) {

      if (contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        return contacts[i][prop];
      } else {
        return "No such property";
      }
    }
  }
  return "No such contact";
}

console.log(lookUpProfile("Harry", "likes"));
console.log(lookUpProfile("Kristian", "likes"));
console.log(lookUpProfile("Made Up Person", "likes"));
console.log(lookUpProfile("Akira", "Made Up Property"));
```

Comment: Mmm but I don't understand... why outside..? Why can't it be inside the else of the first if... ? Isn't that logic?

And why the for stops there..

I can't code if i don't understand the way it works..

Comment: `return` exits the function - so if the first contact isn't the person you're looking for, then it'll flow to the `if`, right? You were returning - and that will exit the function with the message `No such contact`. Does that make sense @Ana?

Comment: Ohhh I seee, Guess I need a lot to learn yet :D Thank u very much!

Answer (score 0):

In your current code if the first element of array doesn't match the current passed name than it goes to else block and return "No such contact" ( eventually just checks first element only )

You're returning wrongly from else block in for loop, you need to place it out of loop

```js
var contacts = var contacts=[{"firstName":"Akira","lastName":"Laine","number":"0543236543","likes":["Pizza","Coding","Brownie Points"]},{"firstName":"Harry","lastName":"Potter","number":"0994372684","likes":["Hogwarts","Magic","Hagrid"]},{"firstName":"Kristian","lastName":"Vos","number":"unknown","likes":["JavaScript","Gaming","Foxes"]}]

function lookUpProfile(name, prop) {
  for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    if (contacts[i].firstName === name) {
      if (contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        return contacts[i][prop];
      } else {
        return "No such property";
      }
    }
  }
  return "No such contact";
}

console.log(lookUpProfile("Harry", "likes"));
```

Comment: Mmm but I don't understand... why outside..? Why can't it be inside the else of the first if... ? Isn't that logic?

And why the for stops there..

I can't code if i don't understand the way it works..

Comment: @Ana it is outside as if none of the contact matches in loop then only return `no contact found`, if there's any matching contact your function don't event come to this line

Comment: @Ana `In your current code if the first element of array doesn't match the current passed name than it goes to else block and return "No such contact" ( eventually just checks first element only )` this line explains why you need to place it out of loop